# How do I store multiple values in a single variable or list in django views.py?

Tags: python, django, list, view

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def appsc(request):

    allapplied = Applied_Scholarships.objects.filter(user_id = request.user.id)
    for applied in allapplied.iterator():
        print('hi')
        sch_id = applied.scholarship_id
        queryset = ScholarshipDetails.objects.filter(id = sch_id)
        print(queryset)
        context = {"object_list":queryset}

    return render(request,'applied-scholarships.html',context)
```

Here, I need to check the applied scholarships of a student. So for that, I have filtered the entries from the **Applied_Scholarship** table. Now from that, I took **scholarship_id** and filtered the entries in **ScholarshipDetails** table so that I get the name and other details of the scholarship.

Now how do I prevent **object_list** to get overridden?
This code gives me value of only 1 scholarship instead of 2.

Here is my template:

```
            <table class="table mb-0">
                <tr>
                    <th>Scholarship name</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                {% for instance in object_list %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{instance.end_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{applied.status}}</td>
                        <td><a href = "government/home">{{schdets.link}}</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

Do I need to use list?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For not overwriting a variable inside a for-loop you do following:

```py
list_ = []
for x in items:
    list_.append(x.something)
context = {'object_list': list_}
```

But instead of looping over `allaplied` and getting the `id` for `ScholarshipDetails` you could get all at once, like:

```py
sch_ids = [x.scholarschip_id for x in allapplied.iterator()]
queryset = ScholarshipDetails.objects.filter(id__in=sch_ids)
```

You need less database queries and you don't overwrite your variable.

Furthermore: I guess your models have a `OneToOne`-relation, so you could use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to directly get your details while fetching the `Applied_Scholarships`-instances. Then you could get rid of the second `filter` and just use the related field for the details models, e.g. `applied.details` (exact name depends on your model-design).

Comment: When I try to append the queryset into the list, it gives me error saying "append requires a list object but received a ScholarshipDetails" . How do I convert this into list ?

Comment: @waesrgd make sure you have `list_`, not `list`. had a typo in the answer.